# iOS iPhone 5 Choose Correct Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I am attempting to use both storyboards for my iOS project, but I cannot get the code to switch to the appropriate storyboards.  Instead, the code does absolutely nothing.  Is it that I do not have a setting set correctly that controls the switch?  The main storyboard for devices not of the iPhone 5, is called MainStoryboard.  The iphone 5 appropriate layout is called iphone5.  I'm thinking this may be a project configuration setting issue.  (This is in my appdelegate.m file).

```
-(void)initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize {

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch


        CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
        {   // iPhone 3GS, 4, and 4S and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th generation: 3.5 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone35
            UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

            // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

            // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
            self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

            // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }

        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
        {   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
            UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone5" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

            // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

            // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
            self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

            // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }

    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

    {   // The iOS device = iPad

        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    }
}
```

Comment: I can see using 2 different storyboards for iPhone vs iPad, but there is a nice button available while your viewing your Storyboard that allows you toggle between the iPhone 5 screen size and the previous screen sizes so you don't have to create 2 whole new storyboards. Is there a specific reason you need separate storyboards?

Comment: No, your solution is what I'm looking for.  Where is this button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest just using 1 storyboard for handling the iPhone 5 vs iPhone 3-4S screen sizes.

When your Storyboard is open, there is a button at the bottom that toggles between the 2 sizes-- you can see in real-time how things will look.

The button is to the left of the Zoom in % Zoom out buttons in the bottom right corner, and looks like this:

[image]

To handle how your object's frame & position will be affected by the screen size change-- you need to set the autosizing properties for each object in your view. You can do this by selecting an object, and in the right Inspector panel, Select the Size inspector like so:

[image]

You see those red lines in the Autosizing box? Play around with them to see how they will effect your object. The inner ones relate to the size (if the width, or height stretches), and the outer ones relate to the position.

I'm not sure about your apps layout but from experience you will probably have to mess with the inner vertical line (how the height will change), and the bottom line (you want that to stay near the bottom).

The more you mess around with each the more you will see what each does.

Comment: Thats helpful, but how can I resize objects specifically for a certain view that don't change with other view configurations?

Comment: If you do not see the Autosizing box with the red lines like you see above let me know, you will have to turn auto-layout off.

Comment: I turned off auto-layout, but my navigation bars go to the bottom of the screen.  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Did you drag it in or did you embed your UIViewController in the UINavigationController by going to Editor-> Embed In-> Navigation Controller? If it is embedded is should never move from the top-- if you dragged it on, click on it and make sure the only Autosizing bar's selected are the Top one, and the width one.