# How to size container view's child view to fit iphone 4 and iphone 5 screens

Tags: ios, resize, storyboard, containers, appdelegate

I'm trying develop my app for iphone 4 and 5. However I encountered problem with container view. My view looks like this:[image: IB Image]

Now, I tried to google a little bit, and found, that I can set size of my views in project settings by uploading picture in different sizes (so that all my views will get resized automatically). This is true for all my views except my container view.

So my second attempt was to size my view in appdelegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    _window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height);
}
```

This unfortunately did nothing to my container view.
Only solution I found so far, was to set height of my embedded table view, by setting it to 458 in size inspector in interface builder. This sets it to fit iphone 5 screen, however on iphone4 (and in simulator) it is too much and some of my rows are below screen (as I expected).

If anyone could help me, I'll be glad, because I really don't know how to deal with this problem ;)

Comment: I'm not using stroyboard, but check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266776/ios-iphone-5-choose-correct-storyboard), it may help

Comment: Thx I'll definitely check it out 0xEC74

Comment: So what is the problem with your container view? The child controller should be the same size as the container view, which should resize itself automatically with different screen sizes. Are you not getting this behavior?

Comment: Nope I'm not getting it. It's not resizing automatically

Answer (score 0):

Well I would look into your constrains and your origin settings, incase you made any changes without knowing. Here is an example:
 [image]

Make sure the origin settings are set to the top left "dot" like in the image and check your constrains parents (Superview in this case). Tip: The key to editing constraints in interface builder is never to drag and drop anything once you've added it to the view. Move and arrange things by editing the constraints instead.

You can also turn off the Auto-layout and do it manually

[image]

Here is also a great article on [auto-layout in interface builder](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/) and [apples own documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html) on Resizing the View Controller’s Views and children's views (which a container is).

My last tip before you either have to try my last solution (which is underneath) or get the answer from someone else, is to check your architecture settings.

[image]

If that does not help it might be caused by some unknown random error that is hard to find, and I would suggest that you try to clean your project first by clicking/holding down "Shift" "command" and "K", and if that does not work, just start a totally new project and copy all the code and files over to the new project. This should help since the problem that you have should not be accruing since it should be dealt with automatically, but seemingly random errors do accrue on occasions.

I hope one of the tips help you out, if not I'm sorry.